# How to query data, and group them by month to feed line charts?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm facing some issue and I have no idea what keyword should I search for in the MongoDB docs.

So the problem is, I have a list of transactions record made by users right now, eg as below.

```
[
    {
        "_id": Some_Mongo_ID,
        "invoiceId": "ABCDEFG",
        "username": "randomUser"
        "amount": 80,
        "createdAt": "2022-04-18T06:59:07.836Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": Some_Mongo_ID,
        "invoiceId": "ABCDEFG",
        "username": "randomUser"
        "amount": 70,
        "createdAt": "2022-04-19T06:59:07.836Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": Some_Mongo_ID,
        "invoiceId": "ABCDEFG",
        "username": "randomUser"
        "amount": 55,
        "createdAt": "2022-05-18T06:59:07.836Z"
    },
        ...
]
```

In a Dashboard app that I'm working with right now, there's a line chart. To feed the line chart I will need to somehow make query/aggregation on the raw data of Transactions that I have, and group them into an array of objects, containing the months and total spend during that month.

```
[
    {
      "period": "2022-04",
      "totalSpending": 900
    },
    {
      "period": "2022-05",
      "totalSpending": 2000
    },
    {
      "period": "2022-06",
      "totalSpending": 367
    },
      ...
]
```

Is it technically possible to query/aggregate data that I have and make them group by months into an array as showed above?

Would be appreciated if any info is provided. Thanks

Comment: Unless you need the individual transaction data, it's probably more efficient to do this directly in a DB query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GChW9mR65gT)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        month: { //Group by Month
          "$month": "$createdAt"
        },
        year: { //Group by Year
          "$year": "$createdAt"
        }
      },
      "totalSpending": { //Accumulate sum for the group
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { //You can ignore this if the group format is ok
      "totalSpending": 1,
      "period": { //To form the expected string
        "$concat": [
          {
            $toString: "$_id.year"
          },
          "-",
          {
            $toString: "$_id.month"
          }
        ]
      },
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: hey there. Really appreciate your help. It's really helpful and exactly what I need. I just had to add one $match pipeline on top to make it query per user's result. Never thought of you can use $concat to form expected string in return too.

Comment: You can also group by `{_id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$createdAt", unit: "month" } } }` (in MongoDB version newer 5.0), For the output use `{ $dateToString: { date: "$_id", format: "%Y-%m" } }`

Comment: @MrrEluu Consider Wernfried' suggestion if you use 5.0. Thanks for educating me Wernfried. You can use format option of dateToString instead concat